# Django deployment 500 server error, nothing in logs

Tags: django, openshift

Im getting a single line entry in my log that just says 'GET 500 27' and the browser is showing a 500 error as well naturally. If the log is not giving me anything useful, then how can I go about troubleshooting this to see where the error is happening in Django?

EDIT: I should add that my dev environment is working just fine.

EDIT II: yeah allowed hosts is set properly. It works fine in the django dev environment, and it was working fine in openshift until I started getting this error.

Comment: It is probably worth editing your question to include (a) the web server you are using (Django's built in dev server or something else) and (b) any logging related configuration you have.

Comment: Give more details about your setup, we can't conclude anything from your question

Comment: Do you have ALLOWED_HOSTS and SECRET_KEY set properly in your settings?

Comment: specifically, what details would you like to know about the setup, I am not sure what details are important and what is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the traceback started showing again (I had to: CHROME: right click > Inspect element > network > preserve log)

and then I found out that my problem was that I unknowingly deleted the MySQL database because I thought I wasn't using it. I had to then remove the SQLite db from gitignore and then re-push everything to use SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have 'EMAIL_BACKEND, EMAIL_HOST, etc' set in the settings.py
and set your `ADMINS = (('Your Name', 'youremail@email.com'),)` in there as well.
that way errors should get sent to you via email.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 500 error belongs to these settings on settings.py:

```
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG') == 'True'`
```

Resolved by replacing with -

```
DEBUG = True
if os.environ.get('DEBUG') is not None:
    DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG') == 'True'
```